# How to get the count of products in Akeneo PIM API search

Tags: php, json, api, akeneo

I'm new to the Akeneo PIM API and currently using a "fetch" connector to grab product and category information via the API.

I've managed to get the access working fine and I can bring back product information based on filters but I'm struggling to find out how many products are actually being returned.

According to the API documentation, there's a query parameter called "with_count" and if set to "true" you can see the product count in the response.

I've set this to true in the request:

`http://example.com/api/rest/v1/product-models?with_count=true&pagination_type=search_after&limit=1&search={"brand":[{"operator":"IN","value":["brand_fred_perry"]}],"department":[{"operator":"IN","value":["department_polo_shirts"]}]}`

But I can't see it in the response:

```
{
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://example.com/api/rest/v1/product-models?with_count=true\u0026pagination_type=search_after\u0026limit=1\u0026search=%7B%22brand%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22IN%22,%22value%22:%5B%22brand_fred_perry%22%5D%7D%5D,%22department%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22IN%22,%22value%22:%5B%22department_polo_shirts%22%5D%7D%5D%7D"
      },
      "first":{
         "href":"http://example.com/api/rest/v1/product-models?with_count=true\u0026pagination_type=search_after\u0026limit=1\u0026search=%7B%22brand%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22IN%22,%22value%22:%5B%22brand_fred_perry%22%5D%7D%5D,%22department%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22IN%22,%22value%22:%5B%22department_polo_shirts%22%5D%7D%5D%7D"
      },
      "next":{
         "href":"http://example.com/api/rest/v1/product-models?with_count=true\u0026pagination_type=search_after\u0026limit=1\u0026search=%7B%22brand%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22IN%22,%22value%22:%5B%22brand_fred_perry%22%5D%7D%5D,%22department%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22IN%22,%22value%22:%5B%22department_polo_shirts%22%5D%7D%5D%7D\u0026search_after=qtTUjg%3D%3D"
      }
   },
   "_embedded":{
      "items":[
         {
            "_links":{
               "self":{
                  "href":"http://example.com/api/rest/v1/product-models/aw19m3600106"
               }
            },
            "code":"aw19m3600106",
            "family":"default",
            "family_variant":"default_size",
            "parent":null,
            "categories":[
               "fred_perry_polo_shirts",
               "fred_perry",
               "polo_shirts"
            ],
            "values":{
               "brand":[
                  {
                     "locale":null,
                     "scope":null,
                     "data":"brand_fred_perry"
                  }
               ],
               "color":[
                  {
                     "locale":null,
                     "scope":null,
                     "data":"color_burgundy"
                  }
               ],
               "department":[
                  {
                     "locale":null,
                     "scope":null,
                     "data":"department_polo_shirts"
                  }
               ],
               "name":[
                  {
                     "locale":null,
                     "scope":null,
                     "data":"Fred Perry M3600 Burgundy Polo Shirt"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "created":"2020-03-26T08:40:24+00:00",
            "updated":"2020-03-26T08:40:24+00:00",
            "associations":{
               "PACK":{
                  "products":[

                  ],
                  "product_models":[

                  ],
                  "groups":[

                  ]
               },
               "SUBSTITUTION":{
                  "products":[

                  ],
                  "product_models":[

                  ],
                  "groups":[

                  ]
               },
               "UPSELL":{
                  "products":[

                  ],
                  "product_models":[

                  ],
                  "groups":[

                  ]
               },
               "X_SELL":{
                  "products":[

                  ],
                  "product_models":[

                  ],
                  "groups":[

                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The API documentation also says I should be seeing "current_page" in the response but as you can see above it's not there...

### Edit

Turns out I can't see it when setting the "pagination_type" to "search_after".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pagination_type` "`search_after`" is not compatible with the parameter `with_count`.

As you don't need to retrieve a big amount of products, you can safely us the "`page`" `pagination_type` or remove this parameter as it's the default value and you should get back the product counter.

Here is the api documentation section that explains this: https://api.akeneo.com/documentation/pagination.html